# Find where a series of timestamped etas reach the end

Tags: excel, google-sheets, linear-interpolation

I have a computer program running, which occasionally prints out the current time and how long until it's finished. Unfortunately, the estimate is really bad, but with a half-dozen data points, I figured I could just do a linear interpolation or something to find when it should actually finish. I'd like an excel or Google Sheets equation, just because that's where I've been storing the output, but I'm not going to insist on it.

Here are the datapoints I have currently:

| ETA(hours) | Projected Completion | As of |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 37.7 | 12/27 5:04 AM | 12/25 3:23 PM |
| 34.81 | 12/27 3:13 AM | 12/25 4:25 PM |
| 31.21 | 12/27 1:23 AM | 12/25 6:11 PM |
| 27.38 | 12/26 11:16 PM | 12/25 7:54 PM |
| 23.18 | 12/26 9:08 PM | 12/25 9:58 PM |
| 18.32 | 12/26 6:27 PM | 12/26 12:08 AM |
| 12.92 | 12/26 3:33 PM | 12/26 2:38 AM |
| 6.79 | 12/26 12:25 PM | 12/26 5:38 AM |

Also, happy holidays, I guess.

Comment: do you also have percentages (amount completed) for each of those times? this would be ideal for forecasting the expected crossover at 100%

Comment: I don't have those, but I'm not sure they're necessary. I'm essentially asking for a time t where the function would estimate the time to completion to be 0. Edit: Give me a second to add a third column that might help.

Comment: if the "As Of" is in column C, and the "ETA Hours" is in column A, with 1 header row and the data starting in row 2, maybe this: `=TEXT(TREND(C2:C9,A2:A9,1,TRUE),"mm//dd/yyyy hh:mm")`

Comment: Thanks, that has 12/26 8:13 AM as its output, so I should know soon enough.

Comment: =TEXT(TREND(C2:C10,A2:A10,0,TRUE),"mm//dd/yyyy hh:mm") seems to have been the correct input, which correctly predicted 8:40 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation purposes:
The goal of this question was to do a linear interpolation of the ETA (in hours) to obtain a projected completion timestamp (in the regular sheets date format).
In order to achieve that, the trend function is used (see the docs [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094263?hl=en)),
so the answer would look something like like:

```
=TEXT(TREND(C2:C9,A2:A9,1,TRUE),"mm//dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```